# Is universe expanding from inside or is being stretched from outside?

Tags: universe

Just like in the title, Is universe expanding from inside or is being stretched from outside ?

The way I see it from observations. There is a lot of talking about nothing and something.

So lets say you have a sphere of nothing ( empty space ) and you are trying to stretch it from every side equily ( sphere ). We are adding "something" to "nothing" ( stretching energy which is everywhere inside sphere ).

If we know that energy turns into matter ( which generates gravity).

Isn't it logical to think that something is pulling on us, and from energy of pulling there is a matter which is the opposite of nothing so it fights with expanding space ?

Also if we assume that this expanding energy is everywhere. then if we zoom to atomic scale we should see strings that is a middle process of fighting two forces ? ( Nothing against something, Space against matter=gravity )

The only way for nothing to weight something is that nothing needs to have an edge (sphere edge).

Also when we think that mass comes from energy then this means that mass is its after effect ( a child ) Could we say that There is only nothing ( empty space ) and energy ( visible universe ) ?

Why we don't take gravity as the opposite of stretching ? If we stretch something then the energy is minus ( -energy ) the opposite of -energy is energy ( gravity, because gravity comes from energy ).

Nothing = Dark Matter

Stretching energy ( -energy ) = Dark energy

Opposite to Dark energy is energy ( visible energy, light etc. )

Opposite to Dark Matter is Matter (visible universe ).

Isn't it logical to assume that There is only x vs y ? We see it everywhere, even math is comparison between something and nothing. "-x" <> "x" and "-y" <> "y" .

Also isn't it logical to think that time is the difference between space stretching and counter force in form of gravity ? If we are something and we are expanding, this means we are never at the same spot as yesterday as we are constantly moving. We can only go forward in time because we are always farther from point of stretching origin. To go back in time we would need to be shrinking, not expanding.

Lets say that there is no x,y so there is no difference between something. This means that time is not there either ?

Comment: Note that there does not need to be an "outside" of the universe. The universe probably has no boundary and need not have an ambient space. This alone makes nearly every notion you put forth somewhat dubitable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I agree with either of your options... Don't think about the Universe as a big room with things in it, whose walls are moving outward. Rather it is like a ball of dough that is baking in an oven and the dough is expanding everywhere.

The rate of expansion of a particular region of space is proportional to size of the region. So the space between our galaxy and a galaxy a million light years away is expanding quite fast (Hubble's constant of 160 km/sec per million light-years - enough to cause a red-shift!). The space between our sun and Alpha Centauri is also expanding but at a much lower rate (about 70 cm/sec) because the distance is much less. In fact, the space between your head and your computer screen is expanding, but only at about half-a-nanometre per year. So you don't notice it.